# emacs+auctex: prevent region filling when inserting itemize

Tags: lists, itemize, emacs, auctex

When inserting an `itemize` environment around some text (using C-c C-e) AucTeX insists on doing paragraph-filling on said text, which messes up my layout. Is there a simple way to prevent that ?

Context is, I'm turning plain-text notes into a latex document. When the plain-text draft contains:

```
- first item
- second item
```

I want to select the two lines, type C-c C-e itemize RET, and obtain:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item - first item
- second item
\end{itemize}
```

Then it would be easy to add the missing `\item` commands where required. But instead, AucTeX calls `LaTeX-fill-region` on the content of the environment (cf `latex.el` line 686) and I end up with:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item - first item - second item
\end{itemize}
```

Obviously this is no big deal for such a short list. But for some longer text it is, because the structure of my list is lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source and auctex *really* wants to fill the region-)

Obviously you could change everywhere that needs changing but it would be simpler just to write a simple function that just inserted begin and end not really based on the auctex code.

or simplest is to select the region

```
- first item
- second item
```

and use `C-w` `C-x` `C-e` `<return>` `C-y`

Ie kill the region insert the environment around nothing then yank the region back. It's only a couple of extra keystrokes so less than it would take to write a new function unless you are doing this a lot:-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `LaTeX-env-item` function in [`latex.el`](https://github.com/jwiegley/auctex/blob/master/latex.el) calls `LaTeX-fill-paragraph`.

Fortunately, this behavior can be changed with [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) these functions. The following code turns off `LaTeX-fill-paragraph` while `LaTeX-env-item` is running.

```lisp
;; Empty function that just do nothing
(defun my-empty-func (orig-func &rest args))

;; Call orig-func with LaTeX-fill-paragraph disabled
(defun my-tex-no-fill (orig-func &rest args)
  ;; Replace LaTeX-fill-paragraph with my-empty-func
  (advice-add 'LaTeX-fill-paragraph :around #'my-empty-func)
  (let ((res (apply orig-func args))) ;; Call orig-func
    ;; Enable original LaTeX-fill-paragraph
    (advice-remove 'LaTeX-fill-paragraph #'my-empty-func)
    res))

;; Disable filling for LaTeX-env-item
(advice-add 'LaTeX-env-item :around #'my-tex-no-fill)
```

Note that this code uses `advice-add`/`advice-remove` functions that have been introduced in Emacs 24.4.

EDIT:

Shorter version using `ignore` function (thanks to [giordano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31416/giordano) for his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118958/emacsauctex-prevent-region-filling-when-inserting-itemize/278452?noredirect=1#comment670574_278452)):

```lisp
;; Call orig-func with LaTeX-fill-paragraph disabled
(defun my-tex-no-fill (orig-func &rest args)
  ;; Disable LaTeX-fill-paragraph
  (advice-add 'LaTeX-fill-paragraph :around #'ignore)
  (let ((res (apply orig-func args))) ;; Call orig-func
    ;; Enable LaTeX-fill-paragraph
    (advice-remove 'LaTeX-fill-paragraph #'ignore)
    res))

;; Disable filling for LaTeX-env-item
(advice-add 'LaTeX-env-item :around #'my-tex-no-fill)
```

Comment: You don't need to define a new "empty" function, `ignore` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick & dirty function for you:

```lisp
(defun itemize (beg end) 
 "wrap the active region in an 'itemize' environment,
  converting hyphens at the beginning of a line to \item"
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (insert "\\begin{itemize}\n")
    (while (re-search-forward "^- " nil t)
      (replace-match "\\\\item "))
    (end-of-buffer)
    (insert "\\end{itemize}\n")))
```

Select the region you want to convert and call `M-x itemize`. This hard-codes "- " at the beginning of a line as the beginning of an item. If you use other conventions, you'll need to tweak it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-<return>` at the right position (after `first item`), which insert a return and a `\item`.  `M-<return>` is also great when using `RefTex-mode` in `align`-environments, as it inserts `\\` and the next label.

(More a comment, but too low reputation as a new user to comment :/)

Comment: Sure. And my point is precisely that I want to be able to type `<M-return>` _at the beginning_ of each line without having to go fishing for my dashes :-)